# When is the Subgroup Lattice Graded?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $G$ be a finite group.  We say that the lattice of subgroups of $G$ is **graded** if it is possible to assign a non-negative integer rank $r(H)$ to each subgroup $H$ in such a way that the following two properties hold.

- If $H \leq K$, then $r(H) \leq r(K)$.
- If $H \leq K$ and no group is strictly between $H$ and $K$, then $r(K)=r(H)+1$.

Examples of groups with graded lattices include

- Abelian groups ($r(H)$ is the number of prime factors in $|H|$, counted with multiplicity).
- The symmetric group $S_3$ (the identity has rank $0$, the whole group has rank $2$, all other subgroups have rank $1$)
- The quaternion group (identity has rank $0$, $\{1, -1\}$ has rank $1$, the subgroups generated by $i$, $j$, and $k$ have rank $2$, and the whole group has rank $3$).

An example of a group without a graded lattice is $A_4$, the alternating group on $4$ elements.  One way to see this is to note that you have the two chains 
$$\{e\} \leq \{e, (12)(34)\} \leq \{e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\} \leq A_4$$
and
$$\{e\} \leq \{e, (123), (132)\} \leq A_4$$
The two chains are both maximal ($A_4$ has no subgroups of order $6$), but looking at the two chains give conflicting values for the rank of the whole group vs. that of the identity.

**Is there a general description of which groups do or do not have graded subgroup lattices?**

I feel like this should have been studied somewhere before, but can't find anything on it.

Comment: I think that these groups (i.e. with graded subgroup lattice) are precisely the supersoluble groups and that the result is due to Iwasawa.

Comment: I guess "catenary" would be a better terminology (it's used in ring theory for basically the same meaning, while "graded" is widely used for unrelated concepts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you the_fox for bringing Iwasawa's result to my attention.  This answer is expanding on their comment.

Call a group $G$ *Supersolvable* (or *Supersoluble*) if there is a chain of subgroups

$$e=H_0 \vartriangleleft H_1 \dots \vartriangleleft H_m = G$$

Such that each $H_i$ is normal in $H_{i+1}$ and each quotient $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is cyclic (as opposed just being Abelian as required by regular solvability).  There are a few characterizations of these groups, but one (due to Iwasawa in 1941's "Über die endlichen Gruppen und die Verbände ihrer Untergruppen" ([MathReview](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&extend=1&l=100&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=iwasawa&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=72&mx-pid=5721), paper doesn't seem to be available online) is that these are the groups whose maximal chains of subgroups all have the same length, which is equivalent to having a well-defined rank function.

Hall's book *The Theory of Groups* devotes section 19.3 and portions of section 10.5 to this theorem and its proof.  10.5 also mentions another interesting characterization of these groups due to Huppert: A group is supersolvable if and only if all maximal proper subgroups have prime index.

Comment: A good general reference on subgroup lattices is the book _Subgroup lattices of groups_ by Roland Schmidt, if it is in your library.  (In particular, it discusses Iwasawa's theorem and context.)